# Keyboard stopped working on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 ProX (AMD) 14ARH7 (EndeavourOS)

Tags: keyboard, kernel-modules, endeavouros

After a recent system update, the built-in keyboard stopped working propperly. I googled the issue, but there seems not to be any known issue. The problem arose on July 29, 2023 after upgrading the system from kernel 6.4.6-zen1-1-zen to 6.4.7-zen1-1-zen.

other packages, which were updated on July 29:

```
abseil-cpp-20230125.3-2
alsa-card-profiles-1:0.3.76-2
ca-certificates-mozilla-3.92-1  
freeplane-1.11.5-1
glslang-12.3.1-2
gspell-1.12.2-1
gst-plugin-pipewire-1:0.3.76-2
lensfun-1:0.3.4-3  
libcamera-0.1.0-1  
libcamera-ipa-0.1.0-1
libpipewire-1:0.3.76-2
linux-6.4.7.arch1-1
linux-headers-6.4.7.arch1-1
linux-zen-6.4.7.zen1-1
linux-zen-headers-6.4.7.zen1-1
nss-3.92-1
pipewire-1:0.3.76-2
pipewire-alsa-1:0.3.76-2
pipewire-audio-1:0.3.76-2
pipewire-jack-1:0.3.76-2
pipewire-pulse-1:0.3.76-2
python-yaml-6.0.1-2
virtualbox-host-modules-arch-7.0.10-5
```

Related posts: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/15dbhzy/latest_kernel_could_break_keyboard_on_some_lenovo/?rdt=34893

In Win11, the keyboard works fine.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Since archwiki reports a kernel issue, did you try with a different kernel? I would try both official repo'ed kernel {`linux`,`linux-lts`} both greater than `6.0`, let we know

Comment: I tried linux, which does not work...

Comment: You said **a system update** broke the keyboard; if you revert back to previous working known versions (not only the kernel, the entire system), does it fix your issue?

Comment: I did just that and edited the question with all packages, which were updated, when I encountered this problem.

Comment: the issue is fixed in kernel '6.4.11-arch1-1'

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the keyboard and reseating the ribbon cables. There's little slots on the bottom of the keyboard. Push  all those up. Then some screws in the middle of the keyboard should  appear. They're captive, so they won't get lost.  Theres about 5 of them.

Comment: It seems, that you answered a different question. I thought it is clear to be a software and not a hardware issue. However, I updated the question, that in Win11 it works all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Lenovo Yoga 7. Downgraded the kernel (no zen) back to 6.4.4.